# Is there a way/place to query erc1155 smart contract with the token id from opensea

Tags: nft, opensea, erc-1155, query

When you mint an NFT directly on opensea with ethereum and then freeze the data, the NFT metadata is suppose to be stored on ipfs and so does the NFT image.

Normally opensea link to the metadata (Not always, they have a bug), but you’re not suppose to need opensea for proof that the NFT belong to your wallet, right?

Then how can one query the smart contract? In etherscan you can’t query erc1155 smart contracts.

Opensea also gives you token id for every NFT minted. Is there a way/place to at least query the erc1155 smart contract with that?